# Error message received when trying to import turtle (python 3.9, m1 Mac)

Tags: python, tkinter, apple-m1, python-3.9, python-turtle

When I try to import the `python 3` graphical library, `turtle`, on my m1 MacBook, I get an error message:

```
 david@Davids-MacBook-Air Python Coding Files % /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 "/Users/david/Desktop/Python Coding Files/hello.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/Desktop/Python Coding Files/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I see it has the library `tkinter` written in it for some reason. This is weird because on my other Mac, an intel based Mac, with the same `python 3` version, and no library such as `tkinter` install, I didnt get an error message when trying to import `turtle`

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3's `turtle` module has always used `tkinter`.  Your other Mac must have `tkinter` installed.  It used to be shipped with Python, but now you need to install it.  Assuming you use HomeBrew:

```
brew install python-tk
```

Comment: Did you do any web searching on your own before asking this question?  `pip install tk`

Comment: not before, but after. I did that cuz I didn't really know if  `brew install python-tk` will install it for python 3.9. I've noticed some others doing `brew install python-tk@3.9`, do you think I should do that, the more specified command?

Comment: You ought to be able to figure this out.  What version of Python has your homebrew installed?  You can see that in your traceback.  If you use homebrew, it installs the packages that fit the homebrew-installed Python.  And why didn't you just try it?  What is the cost if you're wrong?

Comment: my homebrew installed python 3.9.6, installed it using the `brew install python@3.9` command

Comment: I also have python 3.8.2 that got installed with the command line tools, and so that's why im hesitate and think that it might accidentally install tk for python 3.8.2 instead of python 3.9.6

Comment: Homebrew will install addons to what homebrew installed.  Even if it did install it to the system Python, what's the harm?  It's quicker to try it than it is to wait for answers here.

Comment: because its not recommended to install things for the system python

Comment: Maybe, but you're not going to hurt anything.  That's why homebrew manages its own installation.

Comment: ok, I will use the `brew install python-tk` command to install tkinter for python 3.9.6

Comment: It seems as if it does not work with "port" (?)